# How to make something rotate towards touch in corona sdk?

Tags: android, rotation, coronasdk

I've been stuck at this and i haven't found any help. Can you please show the solution with some example? Thanks.

Comment: Start by making something rotate? Then start by finding out how to register a touch event? Then find out how to move an object? Then find out how to get the position of the touch? Then find out how to move a point towards another? This is how programming works. You build it up slowly. It is unlikely you will find a function called "RotateObjectTowardsTouchPoint"

Comment: Thanks man, but i would rather like to be helped with some trigonometry. :)

Comment: You are welcome, but StackOverflow is a place where you get answers to questions about an actual programmable problem you have faced. Right now we cant help you with trigonometry since you have no trigonometry problem. You need to try to build something, and when you encounter an actual problem, then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example. Not sure how you want the rotation and transition but it has the basics of what you need.

```
local star = display.newLine( 200, 90, 227, 165 )
star.anchorX = 0.2257
star.anchorY = 0.5

star.x = display.contentCenterX 
star.y = display.contentCenterY
local function listener1(  )
  -- body
end

local function rotate(event)
  timer.performWithDelay(1000, function() star.rotation = star.rotation + 6; end, 0)
transition.to( star, { time=15000, alpha=1, x=(event.x), y=(event.y), onComplete=listener1 } )

end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", rotate)
```